# ndarray concatenate error

Tags: python, numpy

I wish to concatenate the following arrays:

```
a=np.array([[1,2],[1],[2,3,4]])    
b=np.array([[20,2]])    
np.concatenate((a,b),axis=0)
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-42253341965b> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate((a,b),axis=0)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

I was expecting the answer to be `[[1,2],[1],[2,3,4],[20,2]]`. If `b=np.array([20,2])` instead the concatenation works fine except I get the answer: `[[1,2],[1],[2,3,4],20,2]`

Comment: Don't ask two questions in one question; create a separate question for that please.

Comment: Make `a` and `b` Python `lists` and use `+`; this is a better match with MATLAB cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the dtype, ndim and shape of `a`: you'll find that those are `numpy.object`, 1 and `(3,)`, respectively. This is because array `a` contains lists of different lengths, so each list is treated as an object, and `a` is a one dimensional array of objects. I don't know what you are aiming for, but if you want `a` to have an ndim of 2, you'll need to make sure all the lists have the same length.

Of course, `b` has an ndim of 2, since it contains only one (nested) lists, which will always result in a regular n-dimensional array.

The error message is then obvious: you're trying to concatenate two arrays with different dimensions: that won't work.

To get the answer you're seeking, `[[1,2],[1],[2,3,4],[20,2]]`, you'll need to convert the inner list of `b` into an object as well: then you're concatenating two 1 dimensional arrays of objects.